# Android: get gps Location in background

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I want to retrieve the GPS location, when the application has no focus (running in background).
The following code works fine when the application has focus, but stops receiving gps updates when the app is not focused.

**Service class:**

```
public class GpsTracker extends Service
{

private final LocalBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
protected Handler handler;

LocationManager locationManager = null;

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public GpsTracker getService() {
        return GpsTracker.this;
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handler = new Handler();

    final Context context = this;
    if(locationManager == null) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener());
    }

    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return mBinder;
}

}
```

This class is started from the MainActivity like that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, GpsTracker.class);
bindService(intent, mServerConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
startService(intent);
```

When the app is minimized, the the AsyncTask is still executed but the retrieved Location is no longer updated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should at least start your service as a foreground service. But even that is not enough.

Comment: Yes, i modified the code to start a foreground service. That seems to work now. What do you mean by "not enough" what should be done more?

Comment: It is not enough and i dont know what to do more.